Trying to find a boyscout/summer camp movie from 80s or 90s
I am looking for a movie with very vague tips:

It had teenage/younger boys on some kind of a summer camp or maybe on a trek in the forest on their own, or maybe they were boyscouts.
In one scene (maybe early on in the film) the boys traverse a body of water, where they all get infested with leeches.
The film is from the 80s or 90s (or at least I saw it on TV in the 90s).

This is all I can remember of the film, if someone can help me find this movie I'd appreciate it a bunch. :D 

This sounds like Stand By Me:

It's the summer of 1959 in Castlerock, Oregon and four 12 year-old boys - Gordie, Chris, Teddy and Vern - are fast friends. After learning of the general location of the body of a local boy who has been missing for several days, they set off into woods to see it. Along the way, they learn about themselves, the meaning of friendship and the need to stand up for what is right.

The boys are indeed on a track through the forests and there's also this scene with leeches you describe. And it is from 1986, even though it's set in the 50s.

yes, it's exactly this film, thank you so much for finding it so quickly! :)

I thought, "He cannot possibly mean Stand By Me.  That would be saying, 'There were three guys in a boat, chasing a shark that was terrorizing an island... I don't remember the name.."
